# Multiple testing correction of a two-sided test when the distribution is not symmetric

Tags: multiple-comparisons, likelihood-ratio

I am performing a large number of likelihood ratio tests for whether a value of a parameter (let's call it $p$) in my statistical model is smaller or greater than a particular value (1). The underlying distribution is such that in most cases $p < 1$ and these cases can be identified with more confidence (p-values from a LRT in those cases are generally much lower). However, I'm mostly interested in the cases where $p > 1$ and would like to be able to identify as many of them as possible with a reasonable accuracy.

Because of this, I'm unsure how to perform multiple testing correction (I'm using Benjamini-Hochberg). I can think of the following ways of doing this:

1) Perform a single multiple testing correction for all tests
2) Divide the tests into two separate populations, those where the point estimate of $p$ is less than 1 and those where $p > 1$ and perform multiple testing corrections on the two subsets separately 
3) Randomise the p-values on sites where the point estimate of $p$ is less than 1 and then perform a multiple testing correction on the entire dataset.

I'm pretty certain that 3) is correct but it is also very conservative. Can 1), 2) or perhaps another approach altogether be justified?

Comment: Maybe the LRT isn't the most appropriate test; can you use a 1-sided test for p>1?